# H = {A $\in$ G| there exists f:[0,1]$\to$G continuous, such that f(0)=A, f(1)=I}, Is H normal in G?

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

If *G* is a subgroup of *GL(n;$\mathbb R$)* and *H* = {*A* $\in$ *G*| there exists f:[0,1]$\to$G continuous, such that f(0)=A, f(1)=I}, Is *H* normal in *G*?

Answer (score 2):

To show $B^{-1} A B \in H$, consider the function $g(t) = B^{-1} f(t) B$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Component of Identity is a Normal  Subgroup.

Comment: It seems that Lie condition is abundant.